# Probability between two values on a probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to know what is the value of $\Pr(2<X\le6)$, given the distribution function below:
$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $x<0$} \\
\frac13, & \text{for $1\le x<4$} \\
\frac12, & \text{for $4\le x<6$} \\
\frac56, & \text{for $6\le x<10$} \\
1, & \text{for $x\ge 10$} \\
\end{cases}$$

The textbook where I found this provides a solution that is $\frac12$. However, when I did it I got $\frac56$. The steps I took was first to get the probability distribution $f$ as below:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $x<0$} \\
\frac13, & \text{for $1\le x<4$} \\
\frac16, & \text{for $4\le x<6$} \\
\frac13, & \text{for $6\le x<10$} \\
\frac16, & \text{for $x\ge 10$} \\
\end{cases}$$

And then I did the following:
$$\Pr(2<X\le6) = \Pr(1\le X<4) + \Pr(4<X<6) + \Pr(6<X\le10) = \frac13 + \frac16 + \frac13 = \frac56$$

I believe what the textbook does is
$$\Pr(2<X\le6) = F(6) - F(3) = \frac56 - \frac13 = \frac12$$
But I don't understand why these two methods are not equivalent.

Comment: You are ***almost*** correct about what the textbook does, it should be $F(6)-F(2)$, which is the correct method. This is from the definition of the CDF. $P(2<X\le 6) = P(X\le  6)-P(X\le 2) = F(6)-F(2)$.  What you did is not a correct method. The PMF of this r.v. is $P(X=1)=1/3-0$, $P(X=4)=1/2-1/3$, $P(X=6)=5/6-1/2$, $P(X=10)=1-5/6$.

Comment: Your $\frac13+\frac16+\frac13$ is $\Pr(1 \le X \lt 10)$.  You do not want to include $\Pr(1 \le X \le 2) =\frac13$ or  $\Pr(6 \lt X \lt 10) =0$ in this calculation